# Strange CheckedListBox control behaviour in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a  checkedlistbox control on a form. The multicolumn property is set to true at design time as the items are supposed to be displayed horizontally.
when I run the form and click the last item all the items shift to the left a bit which is very awkward.

Why does this happen and what can be done to stop this behaviour.

I am using VS 2008 on Win7
Regards.

Hello everyone,
setting the ColumnWidth property of the checkedListBox control fixes this. I don't know if this is THE solution but it seem's to work properly.

Comment: Is it possible to post your click event?  The problem might be there.

Comment: This is baked-in behavior for the underlying native ListBox control, it insists on putting the selected item in the first column.  A simple workaround is to make the control narrower so only a single column is visible.  There isn't anything you can otherwise do about doctoring the native control, that code is locked up inside Windows.

Comment: Hi Johan, there is no code in the event yet. As I said it's the only control on the form I was testing it when this came up.

Comment: Your Question is not clear. Can you share the CheckboxList code and screenshot of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's related to something going on about the space needed for the scrollbar.
Maybe you can try to disable/force the horizontal/vertical scrollbars and see if this change something